# Accidentally ran a loop and got banned for RPC -- Any way to get unbanned?

Tags: web3.js, rpc

so I was messing around with useEffect() in React on Devnet and forgot to input the refresh conditions and ended up accidentally triggering an infinite loop. This in turn caused me to get banned from all endpoints including the Mainnet.

Is there any way I can get unbanned? I contacted `support@rpcpool.com` but they left me on read.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you can get unbanned, I am assuming you get a 403, you can set up your own RPC node or use a third party(many are free for first x monthly transactions depending on the provider) as the documentation suggests:
https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints#common-http-error-codes

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

I never got unbanned so I created an account [https://alchemy.com/](https://alchemy.com). It took me 5 minutes to create the account. It's free, so it's perfect for testing.

You then just have to use this url provided
**https://solana-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/your-private-token**